# Getting undefined with custom function execution in grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

Try to execute below custom task:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        log: {
            one: [1, 2, 3],
            two: "Hello World",
            three: true,
            four: {
                five: function() {
                    grunt.log.writeln("Hi");
                },
                six: function() {
                    grunt.log.writeln("Welcome");
                }
            }
        }

    });
    grunt.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ": " + this.data + "\n");

        if (this.target === 'four') {
            console.log(this.data);

            for(var d in this.data) {
                console.log(this.data['five']());

                console.log(this.data['six']());
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'log');
};
```

I am getting below output:

```
Running "log:one" (log) task
one: 1,2,3

Running "log:two" (log) task
two: Hello World

Running "log:three" (log) task
three: true

Running "log:four" (log) task
four: [object Object]

{ five: [Function], six: [Function] }
Hi
undefined
Welcome
undefined
Hi
undefined
Welcome
undefined

Done, without errors.
```

I am not able to understand while executing function five and six; it displaying correct output with "undefined". From where this undefined comes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `console.log(this.data['five']());` it means "print out the return value of the function that is defined at `this.data.five`, that is:

```
function() {
    grunt.log.writeln("Hi");
}
```

This function has no explicit `return`, so its return value is `undefined`, and your code prints it out.
To avoid this, change your code to:

```
for(var d in this.data) {
    this.data['five']();
    this.data['six']();
}
```

Or even better, avoid the duplication:

```
for(var d in this.data) {
    this.data[d]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I was thinking was this issue related to Grunt configure mismatch or something like that but yeah i got my answer here too: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1340